# Revoking access to database does not seem to work

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ubuntu, privileges

I'm in charge of a PostgreSQL database for a University course with 23 users and 23 databases. Each user should have access to only one database and if they try to connect to a different one they should get access denied.
I already had a working set but we had to format the server. Now I'm trying to do the same but every user has access to each others databases. I already tried:

```
REVOKE connect ON DATABASE group1 FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE group1 FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE group1 FROM group3;
```

And still I'm able to connect to group1 database by any way:

```
psql -d group1
```

or

```
\c group1
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Edit: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.9.
What I do is login as root, then change user to group3 by:

```
sudo su -
su group3
psql
Enter password:
\c group1
You are now connected to database "group1" as user "group3".
```

Comment: Who are "you"? If you connect as superuser, you *always* have access. (And *always* mention your version of Postgres.)

Comment: Show `\l+ group1` and `\du+ group3` output please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we see so far cannot explain what happens.

If your user `group3` has been granted other roles (is member in other roles), and one of those other roles (recursively!) has access, that would explain it:

```sql
SELECT r0.rolname AS parent, r1.rolname AS member
FROM   pg_roles r0
JOIN   pg_auth_members m ON m.roleid = r0.oid
JOIN   pg_roles r1 ON r1.oid = m.member
WHERE  r1.rolname = 'group3';               -- your role name here
```

For a complete, recursive query, see:

- [How to get all roles that a user is a member of (including inherited roles)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56098/3684)

**Or** if `group3` has superuser privileges:

```sql
SELECT rolname, rolsuper
FROM   pg_roles
WHERE  rolname = 'group3';                 -- your role name here!
```

Comment: I found the glitch in the .sh file to create users. It was using createuser with the -s when it was supposed to be -S so they are not superusers. Your second query found the glitch.

Comment: @CristianEduardoLehuedeLyon: Since [`-S` is the default for `createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-createuser.html) you might drop that option altogether to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE group1 FROM PUBLIC;
```

should be sufficient unless you created `group3` as a superuser.